# Error after adding a dependency to Gradle Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android

I created a new project. He compiles the apk, it's okay. Then I add dependencies in the Gradle for Selenium (2 last). Gradle synchronizes normally, but after trying to compile the apk I get error:

```
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\MAX\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\9bb329db1cfc4e22462c9d6b43a8432f5850e92c\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing org/apache/xerces/impl/xpath/regex/Token.class
Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad utf-8 byte 80 at offset 00000021
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad utf-8 byte 80 at offset 00000021
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\MAX\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\9bb329db1cfc4e22462c9d6b43a8432f5850e92c\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
```

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.test.myapp"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionName "1.0.4"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

        implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
        implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
        implementation files('libs/mail.jar')

        compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.53.1'
        compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-htmlunit-driver', version: '2.52.0'

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bad download.

Try deleting your gradle cache, changing your repository, and rebuilding your jar.

Comment: I've tried to do this many times already ... I even tried to connect other libraries, But nothing happens. Help please understand